# why is $E[E[Y|X]] = E[Y]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have a derivation from my book, I have a problem with the very first line:

$$
\begin{align}
E[E(Y|X)] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty E(Y|x)f_1(x)dx <- \text{why  dx}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf(y|x)f_1(x)dydx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty y \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dxdy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf_2(y)dy\\
&= E(Y)
\end{align}
$$

Now everything after the first integral I understand, thats just splitting the integral up and getting marginal/joint densities. But why do we choose $dx$ in the first integral? seems arbitrary, what is it based on?

Comment: Note that $E(Y)$ represents a constant, while $E(Y \mid X)$ is a function of $X$.

Comment: fair point, forgot that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E[Y\mid X]$ is a function of $X$: its value when $X=x$ is $E[Y\mid X=x]$. We now weight each of these values by $f_1(x)$, intuitively the probability that $X=x$, and ‘average’ (i.e., integrate over $x$) to get the expected value of $E[Y\mid X]$, which turns out to be $E[Y]$.

It’s no different in principle from calculating $E[Z]$ when $Z$ is any other function of $X$, e.g., $Z=X^2$.

Comment: 1. The phrase "the value $E[Y\mid x]$" is absurd and should read $E(Y\mid X=x)$. 2. When one weights the numbers $E(Y\mid X=x)$ by $f_X(x)$ and one integrates, the result is $E(Y)$, not $E(Y\mid X)$.

Answer (score 6):

What does $E[Y|X]$ represent? It is the expected value of $Y$ based on the value/outcome of $X$. **Therefore, it is a function of $X$.** Think of it as $f(X) := E[Y|X]$, if it helps.

Then, $E[E[Y|X]] = E[f(X)]$, which hopefully makes it clear why you integrate with $dx$.

Comment: ohhhh that does help yes! I was thinking of $E[Y|X=x]$, but if $X$ is not yet set, it is of course a function of x..

Answer (score 4):

A random variable $h(Y):=\mathsf E[X|Y]$ is the best (in a certain sense) approximation of $X$ by random variables of the form $g(Y)$ where $g$ is any "nice" (=measurable) function.

It is the best in a sense that it may happen that $X$ cannot be represented as a function of $Y$, so that the behavior of $X$ and $h(Y)$ can be different in general. However, the behavior of $X$ and $h(Y)$ on the level sets of $Y$ is the same, which is expressed in the formula
$$
  \mathsf E[X1_A] = \mathsf E[h(Y)1_A]\text{ for all }A\in \sigma(Y). \tag{1}
$$
Now, clearly the whole set $\Omega$ is among the level sets of $Y$, so a special case of $(1)$ is
$$
  \mathsf E[X] = \mathsf E[h(Y)] = \mathsf E[\mathsf E[X|Y]].
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the tower law for conditional expectation, a result which can be proven easily with a little measure theory. See the book of David Williams (Probability with Martingales). It says that, given two sigma algebras F and G such that F contains G, it follows that E[ . | G] = E[ E[.|F] |G]
Now, since E[. ] is equal to E[ .| trivial sigma algebra], the result you are looking for follows.
This result is much more general than the derivation you give in the question: it is a fundamental property of the conditional expectation. By the way, probability theory is built on measure theory: you should learn it if you want to do any serious work with probability.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are r.v.s. In that case, $E(Y|X)$ is a r.v. itself and its realization depends on the value you assign to $X$. In other words, its randomness comes entirely from the randomness of $X$.

Maybe writing $E(Y|X=x)$ let you understand more clearly why you are integrating on $x$.