# Proof of $E[E[X|Y]]=E[X]$

Tags: probability

I am trying to see why $E[E[X|Y]]=E[X]$ for joint variables $X$ and $Y$.

I understand the following.

> $E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_{X}(x)dx$
>
> $E[X|Y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_{X|Y=y}(x|Y=y)dx$

and

> $f_{X|Y=y}(x|Y=y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}$

so

> $E[E[X|Y]]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\frac{f(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}dxdx$

However, I cannot see how the last expression equals the expected value of X.

Can I have some help? I am familiar with multivariable calculus, but I am not a statistics major and I am not too savvy of these kind of derivations.

Comment: you're summing the [wrong things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

Comment: Also, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440291/why-is-eeyx-ey/440294#440294)

Comment: Thank you ! that answers my question.